# Magento 2 additional image import issue with different url and same name

Tags: magento2, import

I attempted to programmatically import additional images from third-party URLs.Working with root script.

However, the URLs are different, and the names are the same. Does anyone have an idea of how we can upload all the images as additional images?

```
Example :

https:/example.com/100/abc.jpg,  
https:/example.com/200/abc.jpg,  
https:/example.com/300/abc.jpg
```

Here I am adding script with whom I am trying to get result

```
    $pImgs = [];
    $pImgs = explode(',',$product->getNewAdditionalImages());
    
    $i = 1;
    foreach($pImgs as $imgs) {
        
        $imagePathNew = explode("?",$imgs); // image name are like https:/example.com/100/abc.jpg?noimage=logo, so here expload with ?.
    enter code here
        $imagePath = explode("?",$imgs); 

        $mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
            ->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $imagename = explode('.',basename($imagePath[0]));
                
        $subdirectories = [
            substr($imagename[0], 0, 1),
            substr($imagename[0], 1, 1),
        ];
        
        $imageUrl = $imagename[0].'_'.$i.'.'.$imagename[1];
        $imgInDb =  explode('.',basename($imagePathNew[0]));
    
        $imagePath = 'catalog/product/' . implode('/', $subdirectories) . '/' . basename($imageUrl);

        $newImagePath = str_replace(basename($imagePathNew[0]), $imgInDb[0].'_'.$i.'.'.$imgInDb[1],$imagePathNew);
        print_r($newImagePath);
        
        $imageContents = file_get_contents($newImagePath[0]);
        $mediaDirectory->writeFile($imagePath, $imageContents);
        
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, null, false, false);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: which import are you using ?

Comment: I am working with product import root script.

Comment: Could you please share the script here?

Comment: I apologize for missing your message, but the script is messed up. I have no idea how this could have happened.

Comment: @Msquare I have updated with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by following code

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('new_additional_images'); // You can specify the attributes you want to select

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
   
    if($product->getNewAdditionalImages()) {
        $pImgs = [];
        $pImgs = explode(',',$product->getNewAdditionalImages());
        
        $i = 1;
        foreach($pImgs as $imgs) {
            
            $imagePathNew = explode("?",$imgs); // here my image with http://example.com?noimage=logo, so exploded string ? to get actual image url.
            $imagePath = explode("?",$imgs); 

            $mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                ->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $imagename = explode('.',basename($imagePath[0]));
                    
            $subdirectories = [
                substr($imagename[0], 0, 1),
                substr($imagename[0], 1, 1),
            ];
            
            $imageUrl = $imagename[0].'_'.$i.'.'.$imagename[1];
            $imgInDb =  explode('.',basename($imagePathNew[0]));
        
            $imagePathTest = 'catalog/product/' . implode('/', $subdirectories) . '/' . basename($imagePath[0]);
            
            $imageContents = file_get_contents($imagePathNew[0]);
            $mediaDirectory->writeFile($imagePathTest, $imageContents);
            
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId()); 
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePathTest, array('image'), false, true);
            $i++;

            
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks @Msquare for your response.